# Как превратить файл в котором содержится набор чисел в обычный массив от int Java

Tags: java

Входной файл с пробелами, переносами на новую строку и прочим. В нем одни числа, как преобразовать это в одномерный массив от int? Я пробовал через регулярки, все равно между числами остаются символы переноса на новую строку.

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером данных и тем, что у вас уже получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Можно считать из файла с помощью [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("path to file"));
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    int arr[] = new int [list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         arr[i] = list.get(i);
    }
}
```